# A foreign key constraint fails using save() but not failing with create() in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to post an object however I am getting the following error when using `save()` function:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Weird is that if I use `create()` instead of `save()`, it does not fail. Can you guys tell me why it is like that?

This is what I do:

```
$post = new Post();
$input = $request->all();
$post->save();
```

This is my Post model:

```
class Post extends Model{

    protected $fillable = [
        'creator_id', 'title'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is the User model:

```
class User extends Model{

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile_image_url'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```

I have Users table and Posts table. And the relation is that in Posts table the `posts.creator_id` is the `users.id`.

I also want to mention that the refular SQL query inserts data just fine also.

Comment: Could you post both your User model and your Post model? The issue might be that you aliased (named differently) your FK in posts.

Comment: Also, are you using migrations and Eloquent relationships?

Comment: @JackGal I checked my aliases, they are all named the same. And yes, I am using Eloquent relationships.

Comment: Please post your migrations as well. It will help me to identify the FK relationships in your database.

Comment: You are missing your relationship definition in your User model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your question's comments above, you are missing the definition of your Eloquent relationship in your `User` model. Also, it is worth mentioning that it is a good habit to declare the class property `protected $table` in your model to avoid any confusions and make sure Eloquent will work with the table we want it to work with.

In regards to your `User` and `Post` classes, they should be defined as:

```
class User extends Model{

    // protected $table = 'name_of_users_table';
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile_image_url'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}

class Post extends Model{

    // protected $table = 'name_of_posts_table';
    protected $fillable = [
        'creator_id', 'title'
    ];

    public function user(){
        // You need to explicitly set the 'foreign_id' to 'creator_id'
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id');
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you need to make sure you have a `creator_id` column in your `posts` table.

If you need more help, please check [Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), and pay attention to the One-to-Many relationship section.

I hope this helps!

Cheers!

**EDIT 1:**

Explaining why OP's approach doesn't work.

Basically, as per your original question, you have:

```
$post = new Post();
$input = $request->all();
$post->save();
```

At this point, you are not assigning anything to your `$post` object, therefore, whenever `$post->save()` is executed, your object is empty, as in it does not have any properties assigned to it (besides the ones Eloquent assigns to it under the hood). Since you have a constraint (Eloquent relationship), but your object is empty, you get the error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

To get rid of it, you could modify your code to the following, and it will work:

```
$post = new Post();
$input = $request->all();

// NOTE: Will only work if your provided 'creator_id' is set, as in is not null
$post->creator_id = 1; // Change later to: $input['creator_id']
$post->email = 'email@email.com' // Maybe set the email too

// Save the object (this time is not empty)
$post->save();
```

That way, you are saving an instance of your `Post` model that satisfies the FK constraint.

I hope this explanation helps you understand better!

Comment: I did double check that `creator_id` exists in posts table. I added the missing relationship in the Post model but the result is the exact same. I got it working using `$post->creator_id = $request->creator_id;` and then `$post->save();`.

Comment: why don't you try using the factory method? do `Post::create( $input )` where `$input` is `$input = $request->all();` from above...

Comment: Because I was just wondering why one works and another won't.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp please see my response's edit, where I explain why your approach doesn't work. Cheers!

Comment: Ohh, I must be dumb not to realize that. Thank you for that explenation. 

Comment: I'm glad my explanation helped you!

Answer (score 1):

By this, I expect you don't have any `array` in your input form such `<input name="fields[]">`

You should do it as `$post->column_name = 'column_value'`

```
$input = $request->all();
$post = new Post();

foreach( $input as $key => $value ){
    // Doing like $post->title = 'My Post Title'
    $post->$key = $value;
}

// If the creator_id is not in the form
if( empty( $input['creator_id'] ) ){
    $post->creator_id = $user_id; // Or use Auth::user()->getId();
}

$post->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see above inside your models you don't have a problem.

if you can show me what is inside your `$request->all();` with `dd($request->all());`

after that, check if your `$request->all()` have `users.id`

and change this :

```
$post = new Post();
$post = $request->all();
$post->save();
```

if this does not work for you try this :

I think `save` method doesn't work because you don't have `users.id` param inside your `$request->all()`  and `posts.creator_id` is required for create new row. for that, you have tow solutions: firstly you can use `create`  method or you can do that with `save` method but you need to do something like this :

```
$post = new Post();
post->name_of_col_1 = $request->get('name_of_col_1');
$post->creator_id = $request->get('creator_id');
```

Comment: Yep you cleared some things up. My `$request->all()` doesn't contain users.id but creator_id. The second solution works. But is it possible to make the first also work?

Comment: you need to use create method for that like this :  `$input = $request->all();         Post::create($input);`